# Find and replace for the exact value script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a little problem with my Google Apps Script, which I found on the Internet.

If I want to replace "05" with "98", all numbers that contain "5" will be replaced ... such as. "35, 55, 15" etc.

Is it possible to search for the exact value?

```
function dn_nr_tauschen() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Logs")
  var spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var range = sheet.getRange("C11:C");
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  var ui_dn_alt = ui.prompt(  
      'Dienstnummer wechseln \r\n  ',
      'Bitte die aktuelle Dienstnummer eingeben ! \r\n \r\n',
  ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  var to_replace = Number(ui_dn_alt.getResponseText())

  if(to_replace != ""){

    var ui_dn_neu = ui.prompt(  
      'Dienstnummer wechseln \r\n  ',
      'Bitte die neue Dienstnummer eingeben ! \r\n \r\n',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

    var replace_with = Number(ui_dn_neu.getResponseText())

    var result = ui.alert(
      "Will update " + to_replace + " to " + replace_with + " ",
      'Are you sure you want to continue?',
      ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

    // Process the user's response.
    if (result == ui.Button.YES) {

      // User clicked "Yes".
      spread.toast("Will update " + to_replace + " to " + replace_with + " ", "ALERT");

      var data  = range.getValues();

      var oldValue="";
      var newValue="";
      var cellsChanged = 0;

      for (var row=0; row<data.length; row++) {
        for (var item=0; item<data[row].length; item++) {
          oldValue = data[row][item];
          newValue = data[row][item].toString().replace(to_replace, replace_with);
          if (oldValue!=newValue)
          {
            cellsChanged++;
            data[row][item] = newValue;
          }
        }
      }
      range.setValues(data);
      spread.toast(cellsChanged + " cells changed", "STATUS");
    }
    else {
      // User clicked "No" or X in the title bar.
      spread.toast("No action taken", "ABANDONED");
    }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Welcome. Please follow the [tour], read [ask] and add a brief description of your search/research efforts.. Also it will be helpful that you include a link to the original script, a link to a demo spreadsheet shared with anyone with the link to view only and a explanation about why you are using a script instead of the built-in function that does the find/replace.

Answer (score 0):

You want to replace discrete values with replacement values.
The following answer assumes that the values are numeric; but would require only minor changes to adjust for string values.

**Aspects to note**

- `var range = sheet.getRange(11, 3, LR-10);` - the range is defined according to the last row of data, as given by `getLastRow()`. This is a more efficient way to declare the range.
- `if (data[row][0] === to_replace){` - the iteration by "item" is unnecessary. This code performs a simple comparison between the value in Column C and the value to be replaced. The effect is that only cells containing the "to_replace" value are modified.

---

```
function wa14170101() {


  var spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Logs");
  var LR = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange(11, 3, LR-10);
  // Logger.log("DEBUG:the range is "+range.getA1Notation())


  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  var ui_dn_alt = ui.prompt(  
      'Dienstnummer wechseln \r\n  ',
      'Bitte die aktuelle Dienstnummer eingeben ! \r\n \r\n',
  ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  var to_replace = Number(ui_dn_alt.getResponseText())

  if(to_replace != ""){

    var ui_dn_neu = ui.prompt(  
      'Dienstnummer wechseln \r\n  ',
      'Bitte die neue Dienstnummer eingeben ! \r\n \r\n',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

    var replace_with = Number(ui_dn_neu.getResponseText())

    var result = ui.alert(
      "Will update " + to_replace + " to " + replace_with + " ",
      'Are you sure you want to continue?',
      ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

    // Process the user's response.
    if (result == ui.Button.YES) {

      // User clicked "Yes".
      spread.toast("Will update " + to_replace + " to " + replace_with + " ", "ALERT");

      var data  = range.getValues();

      var oldValue="";
      var newValue="";
      var cellsChanged = 0;

      for (var row=0; row<data.length; row++) {
        Logger.log("row = "+row+" data = "+data[row][0]);

        if (data[row][0] === to_replace){
          Logger.log("old value is not equal to new value")
          cellsChanged++;
          data[row][0] = replace_with;

        }
      }
      range.setValues(data);
      spread.toast(cellsChanged + " cells changed", "STATUS");
    }
    else {
      // User clicked "No" or X in the title bar.
      spread.toast("No action taken", "ABANDONED");
    }
    }
  }
```